# How does this statement with multiple evals work?

Tags: linux, bash

```
eval eval \''n='\''{1..'$(dc -e 1000vp)'}'\'' eval eval eval echo '\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\'\''$(('\'\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\'\''$n'\'\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\'\''*'\'\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\'\''{2..$((1000/n))}'\'\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\'\''))'\'\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\'';'\' | tr ' ' \\n | sort -n | uniq -u
```

It prints prime numbers up to 1k! How does it work? And why so many backslashes `\`?

Comment: Can you link the source?

Comment: In general, `eval` works dangerously.  Very dangerously.  One `eval` is a security risk; five stacked in a row is a security nightmare!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Preliminaries

When you want to specify the literal string `'` in bash, you can either double-quote it `"'"` or escape it `\'` such that it is interpreted as the symbol `'` without a special meaning.

When you want to specify the literal string `\` in bash, you can either quote it `'\'` or escape it `\\` such that it is interpreted as the symbol `\` without a special meaning.

`eval` is a command executing its string arguments as if you typed them directly into the console yourself. The string arguments are processed by bash before they are passed on to `eval`. When you call `eval \\` the `eval` command sees only the string argument `\` because of the aforementioned quotation mechanisms. Therefore, every `eval` can half the number of backslashes. Each of the following commands prints just one `\`:

```
echo \\
eval echo \\\\
eval eval echo \\\\\\\\
```

Because there are a lot of `eval`s in the command there are also a lot of backslashes.

An unquoted `{1..3}` is expanded to `1 2 3`. Combining multiple `{..}` generates the cartesian product: `echo a{1..3}b{8..9}c` prints
`a1b8c a1b9c a2b8c a2b9c a3b8c a3b9c`.

## Analysis

#### Multiplication Table

The part before the first pipe `|` generates a multiplication table where all the numbers are from the interval [2, 1000]. Run this slightly altered command to see the multiplication table yourself:

```
eval eval \''n='\''{1..'$(dc -e 1000vp)'}'\'' eval eval eval echo '\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\'\''$(('\'\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\'\''$n'\'\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\'\''*'\'\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\'\''{2..$((1000/n))}'\'\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\'\''))'\'\\\'\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\'';'\' | less -S
```

Bash expands `$(dc -e 1000vp)`, which computes the square root of 1000, which is (floored) 31.

`{1..31}` is assigned to the variable `n` for later use. Up until now, that `{1..31}` is just a literal string. Expansion takes place later on, to generate a cartesian product with another `{...}`.

Deep inside the command, there's a quoted `$((... * ...))`. The `...` are replaced with `$n` (having value `'{1..31}'`) and `'{2..'$((1000/n))'}'` for every number in `n`.
Some more `eval`s expand this to something like

```
echo "$((1*2)) $((1*3)) $((1*4)) ... $((1*1000))
      $((2*2)) $((2*3)) ... $((2*500))
      ...
      $((31*2)) ... $((31*32))"
```

which is then expanded to the final multiplication table.

#### Getting Prime Numbers Using a Multiplication Table

If a number in the multiplication table occurs multiple times, then that number has more divisors than just itself and one, meaning it is non-prime. Therefore, all unique numbers from the table are selected. This is done with the idiom

```
echo "... multiplication table ..." | tr ' ' \\n | sort -n | uniq -u
```